# Window.open with a check for same div content

Tags: javascript, html

I want to create a popup with the following:

- Open popup when a user clicks on div 1 showing content of div 1.
- If content of div 1 already exists in popup, and user clicks div 1, do nothing
- When a user clicks div 2, clear popup and show content of div 2.

I've tried the following, but the conditional statement is always true because the new popup always contains the content of the clicked div.

Can you please give suggestions

Pure javascript is preferred

HTML:

```
<div class="s1" onclick="basicPopup('',this);">Div 1</div>
<div class="s1" onclick="basicPopup('',this);">Div 2</div>
```

JS:

```
function basicPopup(url,t1) {
  popupWindow = window.open(url,'popUpWindow','height=500,width=500,left=100,top=100, resizable=yes,scrollbars=yes,toolbar=yes,menubar=no,location=no,directories=no, status=yes'); 
  popupWindow.document.body.innerHTML = t1.innerHTML;
  return false; //make sure parent window doesn't refresh

  if(popupWindow.document.body.innerHTML==t1.innerHTML){
    return false; //if equal do nothing
  }

  else {
    popupWindow.document.body.innerHTML='';
    popupWindow.document.write(t1.innerHTML);
  }

}
```

Comment: you have a return false before the IFs. Nothing happens after a return.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the `return false` before the `if` statement. A return immediately exits the function and any code after it will not be run.

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/mu6751xk/

```
function basicPopup(url,t1) {
  popupWindow = window.open(url,'popUpWindow','height=500,width=500,left=100,top=100, resizable=yes,scrollbars=yes,toolbar=yes,menubar=no,location=no,directories=no, status=yes'); 
  popupWindow.document.body.innerHTML = t1.innerHTML;
}
```

> Thanks. But when I say "do nothing" if div 1 content exists in the popup, I mean that div 1 should not be clickable, so multiple clicks on div 1 should fail. (ie popup window shouldn't refresh, parent window would cover popup window)

You should do the check before attempting to open a popup window.

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/xrsw4Lou/

Comment: Thanks. But when I say "do nothing" if div 1 content exists in the popup, I mean that div 1 should not be clickable, so multiple clicks on div 1 should fail. (ie popup window shouldn't refresh, parent window would cover popup window)

Comment: @AA I have added a solution for that.

Answer (score 0):

Other than the return false you are also assigning the value of div to window first and then checking, which will ofcourse always return true.

```
function basicPopup(url,t1) {
  popupWindow = window.open(url,'popUpWindow','height=500,width=500,left=100,top=100, resizable=yes,scrollbars=yes,toolbar=yes,menubar=no,location=no,directories=no, status=yes'); 

  if(popupWindow.document.body.innerHTML==t1.innerHTML){
    return false; //if equal do nothing
  }
  else {
    popupWindow.document.body.innerHTML='';
    popupWindow.document.write(t1.innerHTML);
  }
}
```

I removed both:

```
popupWindow.document.body.innerHTML = t1.innerHTML;
return false; //make sure parent window doesn't refresh
```

UPDATE:
Actually we are over thinking here. Just assigning the new value also appear to do the same thing except that it is filling the content every time:

```
function basicPopup(url,t1) {
  popupWindow = window.open(url,'popUpWindow','height=500,width=500,left=100,top=100, resizable=yes,scrollbars=yes,toolbar=yes,menubar=no,location=no,directories=no, status=yes'); 
  popupWindow.document.body.innerHTML = t1.innerHTML;    
}
```

Comment: I am aware of the last block of code you wrote, but that always loads the popup without checking for content. I want to explicitly make it so if the popup content equals the clicked content, do nothing (ie div would be unclickable, popup window would fall below the parent window)

Comment: That is exactly what the first block of code is doing. Assign ONLY if it is not already Assigned. What you were doing was first blindly assigning then checking the Assigned data with the assigned data which was always true. Discard the second block (the updated) and try the first block of my code.